# Outer measure: system of the measurable sets

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

The two maps are defined by: $P( \mathbb N) \rightarrow [0, \infty]$.

1.) 
$\mu_1(A)$ is $0$ if A is empty and $\infty$ if A is not empty. This is not an outer measure, because the sigma subadditivity is not given. Right?

2.)
$\mu_2(A) = $ lim sup $\frac{1}{n} $#$(A \cap \{1, ..., n \})$ is an outer measure. Now I should indicate the system of measurable sets. But what is meant by "system of measurable sets"?

Comment: 1) is just an outer measure, it is actually a measure.

Comment: Albeit a very silly one.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Why is 1.) an outer measure?

Comment: @StMan because it is monotone, $\sigma$-subadditive and satisfies $\mu_1(\varnothing)=0$. Why do you think it is not $\sigma$-subadditive? As spotted by Kavi $\mu_1$ is even $\sigma$-additive.

Comment: @drhab Because of the $\infty$ 's . But yeah, I see...the subadditivity holds. 
But what would be the "system of measurable sets"?

Comment: Every outer measure $\mu$ induces a $\sigma$-algebra. These are the sets $E$ that satisfy: $$\mu(A)=\mu(A\cap E)+\mu(A\cap E^{\complement})\text{ for every set }A$$So in words the sets $E$ that split up any set $A$ in a proper way. Then $\mu$ restricted to these sets (which form a $\sigma$-algebra) is measure. These sets $E$ form "the system of measurable sets". Also see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure#Formal_definitions).

Comment: @drhab Thank you for this comment. What would be the concrete set E in case 1?

Comment: In case 1 it can be shown that *all* subsets of $\mathbb N$ are $\mu^*$-measurable. Consequently $\mu^*$ serves as a measure on the $\sigma$-algebra of all subsets of $\mathbb N$.